# Confusing Labels for Function Generators and Oscilloscopes in Tinkercad

Tags: tinkercad

In Tinkercad, amplitude definition for Function Generators and scale definition for Oscilloscopes are quite confusing. Here is an ss from Tinkercad's function generator:
[image]

On the device `6.20 V` is represented as peak-to-peak voltage, look at the red-lines I've marked. But on the panel right-hand-side, we input it as the amplitude, look at the green line I've marked. Which one is true?

And I cannot deduce the answer using an oscilloscope, because there is not enough info about oscilloscope. (At least, I couldn't find enough info.) Here is the input signal from the function generator above:

[image]

Answer is not obvious, because the meaning of `10 V` placed on `y_axis` is ambiguous. Is it `+/- 10 V` as in `20 V` in total, i.e. the voltage-per-division is `2 V` (first explanation)? Or, is it `+/- 5 V` as in `10 V` in total, i.e. voltage-per-division is `1 V` (second explanation)?  In some Youtube lectures the explanation is first one. But, I'm not quite sure. Because, if `6.2 V` is amplitude and voltage-per-division is `2 V`, then this is noncontradictory. But if `6.2 V` is peak-to-peak voltage and voltage-per-division is `1 V`, then this, too, is noncontradictory. Again, which one is true?

And also, while studying, I've realise that a real life experiment indicates that the second explanation should be true. Let me explain the experiment step by step.

**Theory: Full Wave Rectifier Circuits**

Assume we apply `V_in` as the amplitude, the peak-peak voltage is, `V_peaktopeak = 2 * V_in`. And for output signal we have,

```
V_out = (V_in - n * V_diode) * R_L / (R_L + r_d),
```

where `n` is the number of diode in conduction, `V_diode` is bias of a diode and `R_L` is load resistor. Load resistor is choosen big enough so that `R_L >> r_d` and we get,

```
V_out = V_in - n * V_diode.
```

In a real experiment `r_d` is in between 1 `\ohm` and 25 `\ohm`, and we choose `R_L` on the order of kilo `\ohm`. Therefore, we can ignore `R_L / (R_L + r_d)` part, safely.

And for DC voltage corresponding to the output signal we have,

```
V_DC = 2 * V_out / \pi = 0.637 * V_out.
```

**Sheme of Circuit in an Experiment**

Here is circuit scheme,

[image]

As you may see, for positive half-periode only two of four diode is in conduction. And for negative half-periode, the other two is in conduction. Thus `n` is 2 for this circuit. Let's construct this experiment on Tinkercad. I didn't use breadboard to show more similarity between the scheme of circuit and the circuit built in Tinkercad.

[image]

**Scenerio #1 - Theoretical Expectations**

Let's assume `6.2 V` to be the amplitude. Then, `V_in=6.2 V`. And `V_peaktopeak` is `12.4 V`. As output signal we calculate,

```
V_out = V_in - n * V_diode = 6.2 V - 2 * 0.7 V = 4.8 V.
```

And for DC equivalent we theoretically get,

```
V_DC = 0.637 * V_out = 3.06 V.
```

But in multimeter, we see `1.06 V`. This indicates nearly %60 percantage error.

**Scenerio #2 - Theoretical Expectations**

Let's assume `6.2 V` to be the peak-to-peak voltage. Then, `V_in=3.1 V`. And `V_peaktopeak` is `6.2 V`. As output signal we calculate,

```
V_out = V_in - n * V_diode = 3.1 V - 2 * 0.7 V = 1.7 V.
```

And for DC equivalent we theoretically get,

```
V_DC = 0.637 * V_out = 1.08 V.
```

And in multimeter, we see `1.06 V`. There values are pretty close to each other.

**Conclusion**

Based on these results, we may conclude that `6.2 V` is peak-to-peak voltage, scheme on the function generator is true, the tag "Amplitude" in the description of function generator is wrong and the y-scale of an oscilloscope represents the total voltage half of which is positive and the other half is negative.

***BUT***

I cannot be sure, and since I'll teach this material in my electronic laboratory class, I really need to be sure about this conclusion. Therefore, here I'm asking you about your opinions, conclusions or maybe other references that I've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinkerCAD refers to peak-to-peak voltage as amplitude for some reason. I believe the second explanation (+/- 5V, 10 V total) is correct, based on the x axis and frequency value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).